# How to obtain the distance of maximum probability of finding an electron on x axis

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry

I have the radial component of the wavefunction
$R_{nl}(r)=r^2e^{-2r/3a_{0}}$ so to obtain the maximum distance on x axis I do not know if I have to compute the second derivative of $R_{nl}^2(r)$ or $R_{nl}$ or of the radial distribution function ($r^2R_{nl}^2(r)$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just compute the first derivative of $R^{2}$ and set to zero.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Zhe. I really appreciate if you could give me some insight about why this is the correct option.

Comment: Probability is proportional to $|\Psi|^{2}$, so maximum probability must correspond to $\frac{d(R^{2})}{dr}=0$.

Comment: Sorry, your radial component doesn't already include $r^{2}$, so you do need $r^{2}R^{2}$ because probability is proportional to $r^{2}R^{2}$.